# No module named 'sklearn', but pip and pip3 both show the package exist

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am using python 3.6.0, when importing the sklearn, it shows No module named 'sklearn'.
But I have installed the package in the interpreter, what can I do?
Thanks!

```
(env) (base) MacBook:$ pip3 install sklearn
Requirement already satisfied: sklearn in ./env/lib/python3.6/site-packages (0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: scikit-learn in ./env/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from sklearn) (0.23.2)
Requirement already satisfied: threadpoolctl>=2.0.0 in ./env/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from scikit-learn->sklearn) (2.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.13.3 in ./env/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from scikit-learn->sklearn) (1.19.1)
Requirement already satisfied: joblib>=0.11 in ./env/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from scikit-learn->sklearn) (0.16.0)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy>=0.19.1 in ./env/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from scikit-learn->sklearn) (1.5.2)
```

Comment: share your code and error message?

Comment: [This link](https://pypi.org/project/sklearn/) on the PyPI website suggests using `pip install scikit-learn` rather than `pip install sklearn`. Does that work?